# can i swich from experienced C++ developer to a java application developer?

Tags: java, c++, c

HI

I am a B.E(CS) fresher.I am searching for a job in IT.There are openings for few C++

developers than java developers.Once i get 1-2 years of experience as C++ developer,can

i switch to a java application developer(for survival).

Comment: This is the epitome of a subjective question.

Comment: Ask this on http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

If your smart you can switch to anything. Really.

Specifically regarding programming languages, a language is like a tool used for a particular problem. See yourself as a carpenter rather than a 'hammer operator' or 'saw operator'.

See similar questions:
[Learning multiple languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550239/learning-multiple-languages)

Comment: +1, a language is just a tool.

Comment: languages are maybe just a tool, but SDKs and librarie are toolboxes... I can switch from Java to any language, even brainf*ck, to write "hello world". Writing software is another story...

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can.  Just don't underestimate the effort to learn the language well - you will be benefitted by the syntax looking familiar, and flabbergasted at the size of the runtime library.

If you go for this, write a lot of code.

Comment: I agree with this; I had to take do some Java programming, coming from C/C++, and found the differences to be quite tedious to adapt to.

Answer (score 2):

Possible, but the environments/frameworks for each mean they are more different than the cosmetic syntax similarities might suggest. Don't assume they're basically interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

From an employers point of you I'd say previous 1-2 years experience will not count for much if anything. Friends of mine who have tried this in the past have had to drop a lot in salary and almost start in junior positions again. With only 1-2 years of experience that might not make a big difference in your case.